# Why am I getting undefined method `comments' when using acts_as_commentable_with_threading?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

On the community's #show page, I get:

> undefined method `comments'

I was wondering why was I get this error?

**community_topics_controller.rb**

```
def show
  @community_topic = CommunityTopic.find params[:id]

  @comment = @community_topic.comments.build
  @community_topic.comments.pop

  respond_to do |format|
    format.html # show.html.erb
    format.json { render json: @community_topic }
  end
end
```

**models/community_topic.rb**

```
acts_as_commentable
```

**views/community_topics/show.html.erb**

```
<%= render 'comments/form' %>
```

**views/comments/_form.html.erb**

```
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :comment %><br />
    <%= f.text_area :comment %> 
    <%= f.hidden_field :commentable_id %>
    <%= f.hidden_field :commentable_type %>
  </div>
```

Comment: Did you run the migration? Did you try in the `rails console`? What is the exact error? Did you stop and start your `rails server`?

Comment: @nathanvda Thanks. Yes I did run the migration. I haven't tried rails console. and I restarted my apache server

Comment: @nathanvda I tried to do the same thing on rails console but it still shows the same thing **undefined method `comments'**

Comment: Do you see an error in the logs?

Comment: @nathanvda It says the same thing in log,too. **Processing by CommunityTopicsController#show as HTML
  Parameters: {"community_id"=>"walmart", "id"=>"24"}
  [1m[36mCommunity Load (0.8ms)[0m  [1mSELECT `communities`.* FROM `communities` WHERE `communities`.`community_name` = 'walmart' AND (`communities`.`deleted_at` IS NULL) LIMIT 1[0m
  [1m[35mCommunityTopic Load (0.3ms)[0m  SELECT `community_topics`.* FROM `community_topics` WHERE `community_topics`.`id` = 24 AND (`community_topics`.`deleted_at` IS NULL) LIMIT 1
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 130ms**

Comment: **NoMethodError (undefined method `comments' for #<CommunityTopic:0x0000001ef00e10>):
  app/controllers/community_topics_controller.rb:75:in `show'**

Comment: Which rails version are you using and which version of the gem?

Comment: @nathanvda rails3.2.6 and acts_as_commentable_with_threading (1.1.2)

Comment: It seems that the association is not linked:( But indeed I have acts_as_commentable in my /models/community_topic.rb

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found the answer.
I had to use **comment_threads** instead of **comments** as long as I was using 'acts_as_commentable_with_threading'